# saving and loading object javascript

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Im having an issue figuring out how to save and load my game with the format Ive used

So I have this

```js
var upgradeButtonsData = [
            {icon: 'dagger', name: 'Attack', level: 0, cost: 5, purchaseHandler: function(button, player) {
                player.clickDmg += 1;
            }},
            {icon: 'swordIcon1', name: 'Auto-Attack', level: 0, cost: 25, purchaseHandler: function(button, player) {
                player.dps += 5;
            }}
        ];
```

and I need to save and load it in the same format as the rest of my game for example I am saving my players gold like this
`localStorage.setItem("playerGold",this.player.gold);`

and then loading it like this
`playerGold_save = localStorage.getItem("playerGold") || "0";
this.player.gold = parseInt(playerGold_save);`

I would like to do something similiar with the above code but i am not sure how

also if its relevant heres how I use the above code

```js
onUpgradeButtonClick: function(button, pointer) {
        // make this a function so that it updates after we buy
        function getAdjustedCost() {
            return Math.ceil(button.details.cost + (button.details.level * 1.46));
        }

        if (this.player.gold - getAdjustedCost() >= 0) {
            this.player.gold -= getAdjustedCost();
            this.playerGoldText.text = 'Gold: ' + this.player.gold;
            button.details.level++;
            button.text.text = button.details.name + ': ' + button.details.level;
            button.costText.text = 'Cost: ' + getAdjustedCost();
            button.details.purchaseHandler.call(this, button, this.player);
        }
    },
```

also im using Phaser as a framework

**EDIT:**

Apparently people are confused about what I a asking I *do not* want info on how to save the gold ive already done that it was just an exaple of how I want to save the upgrades like I need to save the 'Attack's level and cost as well as the 'Auto-Attack's level and cost to load on next game play

sorry for any confusion

**EDIT**
I WANT THIS CODE TO BE SAVED

```js
var upgradeButtonsData = [
            {icon: 'dagger', name: 'Attack', level: 0, cost: 5, purchaseHandler: function(button, player) {
                player.clickDmg += 1;
            }},
            {icon: 'swordIcon1', name: 'Auto-Attack', level: 0, cost: 25, purchaseHandler: function(button, player) {
                player.dps += 5;
            }}
        ];
```

Comment: If I understand you want to save the `gold` data after the upgrading ? Or loading before the upgrade ?

Comment: the gold was just an example of how i saving and loading i need to know how i do that with the upgrades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** Here is the code to save and load the upgrader's data :

```
function saveUpgrader() {
  var save = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < upgradeButtonsData.length; i++)
    save.push([upgradeButtonsData[i].level, upgradeButtonsData[i].cost]); // [0] = level ; [1] = cost

  try { localStorage.setItem('upgrader_save', JSON.stringify(save)); }
  catch(e) {
    alert('Failed to save upgrader\'s data');
  }
}

function loadUpgrader() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('upgrader_save'))
    return ;

  try {
    var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('upgrader_save'));

    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      upgradeButtonsData[i].level = json[i][0];
      upgradeButtonsData[i].cost  = json[i][1];
    }
  }

  catch(e) {
    alert('Failed to load upgrader\'s data');
  }
}
```

Call the `saveUpgrader` function to save the `level` and `cost` of each item into the upgrader, or `loadUpgrader` to load them (it will overwrite current level and cost).

*NOTE :* If you want to add items to the upgrader, please add it AFTER the existing elements, like this :

```
var upgradeButtonsData = [
    {icon: 'dagger', name: 'Attack', level: 0, cost: 5, purchaseHandler: function(button, player) {
        player.clickDmg += 1;
    }},
    {icon: 'swordIcon1', name: 'Auto-Attack', level: 0, cost: 25, purchaseHandler: function(button, player) {
        player.dps += 5;
    }},
    // Add the new element here
    {icon: '...', name: '...', level: 0, cost: 75, purchaseHandler: function(button, player) {
      ...
    }}
];
```

If you add the new element BEFORE the others the save will be corrupted and do some bad things.

I hope that helped you :)

Comment: So you want to save and load all the player's info (the entire 'player' object) ?

Comment: where it says `var upgradesButtonData` i wanna save and load everything in there

Comment: Err... There's no `upgradesButtonData` in your code... See my edit, is it what you want ?

Comment: your looking at the wrong portion of code the code your looking at is how upgradeButtonsData is used look at the first section of code in my question

Comment: I don't understand at all what you want to do... You're looking for load and save data if I understand but where ? Before the declaration of `upgradeButtonsData` ?